# Panel regression error in R

Tags: r, plm

I am running an unbalanced panel regression.

Independent Variable is Gross
Dependent Varibales are DEX, GRW, Debt and Life.
Time is Year
Grouping is Country

I have successfully executed the following commands:

```
tino=read.delim("clipboard")
tino
summary(tino)
Dep<- with(tino, cbind(Gross, index=c("Country, Year"))            
Ind<- tino[ , c('DEX', 'GRW' , 'Debt', 'Life')] 
install.packages("plm")
library('plm')          
pandata<-plm.data(tino)
tino          
summary(pandata)  
summary(Dep)
summary(Ind)
```

However, When I run the Command below for results, I get an error.

```
pooling<- plm(Dep~Ind, data = pandata, model= "pooling")
```

gives error below

```
Error in model.frame.default(terms(formula, lhs = lhs, rhs = rhs, data = data,: invalid type (list) for variable 'Ind'
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Please consider reading up on [ask] and how to produce a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Without access to your data, it is impossible to confirm that this will work, but I am going to try to point out several issues in your code that are likely contributing to the error.

This line is fine:

```
tino=read.delim("clipboard")
```

Here is where you start to make errors:

```
Dep<- with(tino, cbind(Gross, index=c("Country, Year"))            
Ind<- tino[ , c('DEX', 'GRW' , 'Debt', 'Life')]
```

`with()` is typically used to create new vectors out of a data.frame. All it does is allow you to drop the `$` notation for referencing variables in a data.frame and nothing else. From the read of your code, you may be thinking that `with()` is actually modifying the `tino` object, which it is not.

Further, when you want to construct a data.frame for use in a regression model, you want all of the right-hand and left-hand side variables in one data.frame or matrix rather than separating them. This is because most modelling functions operate using a "formula" and `data` argument, which are passed to `model.frame()` to preprocess the data before modelling.

This means you presumably want to do something like the following, skipping all of the above:

```
pandata <- plm.data(tino, index = c("Country", "Year"))
pooling <- plm(Gross ~ DEX + GRW + Debt + Life, data = pandata, model = "pooling")
summary(pooling)
```

If you have a lot of right-hand side variables, you can subset your data.frame, with something like:

```
pandata2 <- plm.data(tino[ , c('Gross', 'DEX', 'GRW' , 'Debt', 'Life')], index = c("Country", "Year"))
pooling2 <- plm(Gross ~ ., data = pandata2, model = "pooling")
```

using the `.` notation as a shorthand for "all other columns in the data."

Comment: I still have some difficulty with the syntax. How can I get you the data on this platform.Thanks.

Comment: @Tino Update your question with any new issues you are facing. You may want to try making a small reproducible example using data available in the plm package.